# C# Why is the Form Location Reseting to (0, 0)

Tags: c#, winforms

Whenever I move the form in its maximum state and move the form, the form location will default (0, 0). I use a MouseDown, MouseMove, and MouseUp event.

```
private void TopPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    AdjustingTheForm = true;
}
private void TopPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (AdjustingTheForm)
    {
        scr = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
        LastLocation = e.Location;
        if (FormNormalSize == false)
        {
            FormNormalSize = true;
            CustomForm_Resize(sender, e);
            this.Location = new Point(e.X - 400, e.Y - 15);
            this.Update();
        }
        AdjustingTheForm = false;
        MovingTheForm = true;
        Console.WriteLine("1. " + this.Location);
    }
    if(MovingTheForm)
    {
        this.Location = new Point((this.Location.X - LastLocation.X) + e.X, (this.Location.Y - LastLocation.Y) + e.Y);
        this.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("2. " + this.Location + " " + e.Location);
    }
}
private void TopPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    scr = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
    MovingTheForm = false;
```

Here is where I put the *private* instance members:

```
namespace CustomForm_Practice_1
{
    public partial class CustomForm : Form
    {
        bool minimizeB1MouseDown, maximizeB1MouseDown, exitB1MouseDown;
        bool FormNormalSize;
        bool AdjustingTheForm, MovingTheForm;
        Point LastLocation;
        Rectangle scr;
        .......
```

Here are the results when I move the form (**UPDATED**):

```
1. this.Location: {X=1100,Y=6}
2. LastLocation: {X=1100,Y=6}
3. e.Location: {X=1100,Y=6}

1. this.Location: {X=0,Y=0}
2. LastLocation: {X=1100,Y=6}
3. e.Location: {X=0,Y=0}

1. this.Location: {X=0,Y=0}
2. LastLocation: {X=1100,Y=6}
3. e.Location: {X=1100,Y=6}

1. this.Location: {X=0,Y=2}
2. LastLocation: {X=1100,Y=6}
3. e.Location: {X=1100,Y=8}
```

**OLD** I don't know why x jumps from 703 to 0 and y from 8 to 0. This problem, however, only occurs when the size of the form changes and the form is moved. When the form is at normal size (800, 600). Here is the form resize event:

**New** This time `this.Location` started at X = 1100 and Y = 6 and then it went to (0, 0). e.Location did the same thing. Here is the form resize event:

```
  private void CustomForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormNormalSize == false)
            //Maximized Window
            {
                scr = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
                this.Location = new Point(scr.X, scr.Y);
                this.Size = new Size(scr.Width, scr.Height);
                this.Update();
                //Panel Heights
                TopPanel.Height = 30;
                BottomPanel.Height = scr.Height - 32;
                //Panel Widths
                TopPanel.Width = scr.Width - 2;
                BottomPanel.Width = scr.Width - 2;
            }
            else if (FormNormalSize)
            //Normal Window
            {
                this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
                //Panel Heights
                TopPanel.Height = 30;
                BottomPanel.Height = this.Height - 32;
                //Panel Widths
                TopPanel.Width = this.Width - 2;
                BottomPanel.Width = this.Width - 2;
            }
            //Panel Locations
            TopPanel.Location = new Point(1, 1);
            BottomPanel.Location = new Point(1, TopPanel.Height + 1);
```

The question is, why does the form location go to (0, 0) when this line
`this.Location = new Point(e.X - 400, e.Y - 15);` changes the location that was previously set `this.Location = new Point(scr.X, scr.Y);`?

Comment: Can do formulate a question we can answer?

Comment: @Natrium Okay, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Natrium Try refreshing the page. I fixed the question.

Comment: You claim to use global variables, but I see no global variables! Where are they? In C#, the closest thing to a "global" variable would be a `static` field.

Comment: @AndersTornblad I posted the snippet of code under "I also use Global Variables." I said this because wanted to clarify that I was globally declaring the variables. How should I put it?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko They're *private* instance members

Comment: @Rob I didn't now what they were called. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: You aren't looking at the right place.  It's in "MovingTheForm" not "AdjustingTheForm" (the log shows "2." when the issue happens.  Since you're using panels on top of forms, I think you're going to need to use "PointToScreen" and "PointToClient" to get everything working at the same level.  What's probably happening is you're setting your lastpoint to some point inside of the panel, which it then tries to use with a screen point for calculations.

Comment: @Aaron How do you suggest I fix it?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko can you change it to this in MovingTheForm and see what it returns (I'm handwriting this in, check grammar)? Console.WriteLine("2. " + this.Location + " " + e.Location + " | lastX:" + LastPoint.X.ToString() + " lastY:" + LastPoint.Y.ToString());

Comment: @Aaron I didn't understand what you are telling me to do. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I'm trying to see LastPoint in your log, probably a good idea to add e.x and e.y too, tbh

Comment: @Aaron will that help with the problem?

Comment: It'll help me, yes.  Your values are adding to 0, need to figure out why. I can't make a reproducible copy, so I need to rely on your data.

Comment: @Aaron okay I'll Try that.

Comment: It's not going to fix anything.  It's just going to help me try to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: @Aaron I can't get my files. the files are at my School and I'm off for the weekend. I will tell you when I have them

Comment: @Aaron I added new results to the question

Comment: Ok, great.  Give me a few to look at this.  One thing I notice off the bat - it doesn't look like LastLocation is ever updated.  It is always x=1100, y=6, which was your starting location.  So, it looks like you initially set LastLocation, but then do not update it?

Comment: Try moving "LastLocation = e.Location" From "AdjustingTheForm" to outside of your condition (if).  It should be updating regardless of if it's hitting "Adjusting" or "Moving" I believe...  Let me know if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Aaron That fixed one problem but made a new one. The form won't move now.

Comment: @Aaron I think this is due to LastLocation and e.Location canceling each other `2. LastLocation: {X=1615,Y=606}, 3. e.Location: {X=1615,Y=606}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. PointToClient help me get the LastLocation value. Here is the new code:

```
   private void TopPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            AdjustingTheForm = true;
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            AdjustingTheForm = false;
        }
        LastLocation = PointToClient(e.Location);
    }
    private void TopPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        scr = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
        if (AdjustingTheForm)
        {
            if (FormNormalSize == false)
            {
                FormNormalSize = true;
                CustomForm_Resize(sender, e);
                this.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 400, Cursor.Position.Y - 15);
                this.Update();
                LastLocation = PointToClient(e.Location);
                MovingFormMaximized = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MovingFormMinimized = true;
            }
            AdjustingTheForm = false;
        }
        if ((MovingFormMinimized && this.Location.Y > 0) || (MovingFormMinimized && this.Location.Y <= 0 && e.Y > 32))
        {
            mouseHuggingWall = false;
            this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - LastLocation.X + e.X,
                this.Location.Y - LastLocation.Y + e.Y);
            this.Update();
        }
        else if (MovingFormMinimized && this.Location.Y <= 0)
        {
            mouseHuggingWall = true;
            this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - LastLocation.X + e.X, 0);
            this.Update();
        }
        if ((MovingFormMaximized && this.Location.Y > 0) || (MovingFormMaximized && this.Location.Y <= 0 && e.Y > 32))
        {
            mouseHuggingWall = false;
            this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X -LastLocation.X + e.X,
                this.Location.Y - LastLocation.Y + e.Y);
            this.Update();
        }
        else if (MovingFormMaximized && this.Location.Y <= 0)
        {
            mouseHuggingWall = true;
            this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - LastLocation.X + e.X, 0);
            this.Update();
        }
    }
    private void TopPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        scr = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
        if(mouseHuggingWall == true)
        {
            FormNormalSize = false;
            CustomForm_Resize(sender, e);
        }
        MovingFormMinimized = false;
        MovingFormMaximized = false;
        mouseHuggingWall = false;
    }
```

I added more to the code but the main fix is in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Moving/resizing a form like this can be somewhat fiddly, because the mouse location in `MouseEventArgs` is given relative to the top left of the form rather than in screen coords.

A better way to track mouse coords when you need screen coords is to use the `MousePosition` class along with mouse capture via `Control.Capture = true`.

The easiest way for me to demonstrate this is through a sample app:

1. Create a default Windows Forms app. I'm going to assume that the main form is called `Form1`.
2. Drop onto the main form a `Panel` called `panel1` and set its `Dock`
   property to `Fill`.
3. Add to `panel1` the following handlers: `panel1_MouseDown`, `panel1_MouseMove` and `panel1_MouseUp`.
4. Change the code in `Form1.cs` as follows:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       bool moving;
       Point offset;
       Point original;

       void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {
           moving = true;
           panel1.Capture = true;
           offset = MousePosition;
           original = this.Location;
       }

       void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {
           if (!moving)
               return;

           int x = original.X + MousePosition.X - offset.X;
           int y = original.Y + MousePosition.Y - offset.Y;

           this.Location = new Point(x, y);
       }

       void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {
           moving = false;
           panel1.Capture = false;
       }
   }
   ```

Compile and run the application then click and drag on the main window to move it around. It should follow the mouse as you move it around.

Once you have that working, you should be able to apply the same logic to your application.

Comment: It still didn't fix the problem. The form still moves back to (0, 0). I think the problem has to do more with the Form Resizing and Form Moving.

Comment: Also, I made a custom form. What this means is I set the form border size to `none` and used panels as overlays.